# What are common parameters to use when using Makeham's Law to model mortality in the real world?

Tags: statistics, mathematical-modeling, actuarial-science

I have the following definition for the survival distribution function (which gives the probability that a newborn survives to at least age $x$) under Makeham's Law:

> $$
> S_0(x) = P(X \geq x) = \exp \left( -Ax - \frac{B}{\log(c)}(c^x - 1) \right)
> $$

However, I've been playing with this formula using Python and have been unable to use it to produce realistic looking life tables.

I suspect that this is because I have no idea what values to use for the parameters $A, B$ and $c$. Could anyone please tell me what values might be assigned to these values in real world applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not yet an expert in real-world application, but in this [book](http://www.cambridge.org/vi/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/statistics-econometrics-finance-and-insurance/actuarial-mathematics-life-contingent-risks-2nd-edition?format=HB) I found what they called "The Standard Ultimate Survival Model
Makeham's law" that it is obtained by setting
$$A= 0.00022, \,\ B = 2.7\times10^{-6}, \,\ c = 1.124.$$